Salesforce on record update display an alert
is there any possible way when updating a record there will be a pop up alert?
or any Idea on how to do it? I need a pop up message when the record is updated, I tried creating a record-trigger flow but can't make a subflow of a screenflow

Refer to this: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A7VJkSAN
